# Is keeping track of c# GC objects (to avoid memory leaks) with a weak reference dictionary a good idea?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, weak-references

I have implemented a static class with a dictionary that tracks some objects in my application using weak references.

```
static Dictionary<Type,List<WeakReference>> Monitor;
```

On request (not in production) the garbage collector is forced and the dictionary is returned. By checking the number of "Alive" objects for each type, I can quickly check if I have a memory leak because the number of alive objects is higher than expected.
Given the simplicity and usefulness of this class made by me, I was wondering if there is something better in the dot net framework to keep track of certain objects, let's call them "observable".

Each contribution is highly appreciated.

Comment: I've never had a need to track memory leaks in a C# application, but asking for 3rd party tools/libraries is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm not asking for 3rd party tools, I'm asking for better strategies or something already present in the framework that I don't know

Comment: "... or in some nuget package"

Comment: I hope that now without mentioning nuget we can talk about the question...

Comment: I think most people just use a profiler to find memory leaks.

Comment: as @juharr has pointed out, this is something you should use your development tools for instead of introducing dependencies on some code that is solving a problem you should not have in the common case.

Comment: @juharr Ok, but if I want to programmatically check that the number of "x" "alive" objects present in the GC is equal to the expected one, I can't do it with a memory profiler that does not know how many "x" type objects are expected

Comment: @s4nCh0 The point is that memory leaks in a language with garbage collection should be rare, so people don't commonly code to look for them and instead use a profiler.

Comment: @juharr I agree with you and thanks for your replies. In many years this is the first time I need this and I was wondering if anybody else solved this task and how. For example: is there a direct way to query the GC alive objects without having to populate my own dictionary?

Comment: In Visual Studio, in the memory usage panel there is a "take snapshot" button. It will analize the memory and show you all alive objects, their memory usage etc.

Comment: @Flutterish as I pointed out, the profiler is a very good tool but does not know the application so it cannot highlight leaks or memory issues for you

Comment: FYI: i'm using a similar approach and i find it very useful in helping to determine which objects to look for in a profiling tool (that can tell you _why_ the object is not being collected).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you do not want to use a profiler, then your approach can work. But be aware that your solution itself presents a memory leak as any object you add to it will have a weakreference object present, even after the object has been collected.
You need to periodically remove the weakreferences that are no longer valid, one approach is to remove on add like shown here https://www.chriswirz.com/software/weak-reference-lists-in-c-sharp.
Also remember that you are not using a ConcurrentDictionary so you need to control access to that structure.

If you are okay with spawning another process, you might have success in using the profiling api.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/profiling-overview

You could spawn a process that attaches to the host, collects data and signals back with the results.